# BigQuery query to get a chart for the median time first answer for any tag on Stack Overflow?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, stack-overflow

Based on this blog post - how can I get a chart with the quarterly time that it takes to get an answer on Stack Overflow for any tag?

"[When will Stack Overflow reply: How to predict with BigQuery](https://towardsdatascience.com/when-will-stack-overflow-reply-how-to-predict-with-bigquery-553c24b546a3)"

I want to build a dashboard showing how long it takes to get an answer since the moment a Stack Overflow question is asked, until it gets an answer.

Answer (score 0):

- First join the questions table with the answers table - extracting the first answer.
- Discard questions answered by the same person that posted it - to avoid "0" second answers.
- Don't do a naive `AVG()`, prefer `fhoffa.x.median()` or `EXP(LOG(AVG()))`

Query:

```sql
WITH interesting_tags AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST(SPLIT('google-bigquery,sql,javascript,tensorflow')) tag
)
, question_to_first_answer AS (
  SELECT c.tag, a.id
    , ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(a.owner_user_id AS owner, a.creation_date AS ts, a.tags) LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] question
    , ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(b.owner_user_id AS owner, b.creation_date AS ts) ORDER BY b.creation_date LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] first_answer
  FROM `fh-bigquery.stackoverflow_archive.201909_posts_questions` a
  LEFT JOIN `fh-bigquery.stackoverflow_archive.201909_posts_answers`  b
  ON a.id = b.parent_id 
  JOIN interesting_tags c
  ON c.tag IN UNNEST(SPLIT(a.tags, '|'))
  GROUP BY 1, 2
)

SELECT tag, quarter, COUNT(*) questions
  , ROUND(fhoffa.x.median(ARRAY_AGG(seconds))/3600,2) median_hours
  , ROUND(fhoffa.x.median(ARRAY_AGG(seconds)),2) median_seconds
FROM (
  SELECT tag, id,
    DATE(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(question.ts, QUARTER)) AS quarter
    , TIMESTAMP_DIFF(first_answer.ts, question.ts, SECOND) seconds
  FROM question_to_first_answer
  WHERE first_answer.ts IS NOT null
  AND question.owner!=first_answer.owner
  ORDER BY seconds
)
GROUP BY tag, quarter
HAVING questions>10
ORDER BY tag, quarter DESC
```

[image]

[image]